# Unable to load Controls from Empty Data Template in GridView asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a GridView which is binded with DataTable for the datasource, when there is no records in the underlying datasource i show up the EmptyDataTemplate with Two DropDown (State and City) and based on the State i fills up City.

Now my problem is till i have some records inside the Datasource it works fine, but as soon as i delete the last remaining record from the datasource, it throws error, it switches to the emptydatatemplate but it could not find the States Dropdownlist (based on which i am filling city dropdown). But once i refresh the page it works fine.

I don't understand which event to grab to place the codes

Here's what i am doing

Below function gets the stateid and fills the cities based on it

```
   private void FillCitiesByStateId()
    {
        drpCity = grdLocationView.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("drpCitiesAdd") as DropDownList;
        drpState = grdLocationView.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("drpStatesAdd") as DropDownList; // Fetches the States DropDown from EmptyDataTemplate.
        if (drpState != null)
        {
            objCity.StateId = Convert.ToInt32(drpState.SelectedValue); //It always throws error on this line.
            drpCity.DataSource = objCity.GetCitiesByStateId();
            drpCity.DataTextField = "Name";
            drpCity.DataValueField = "Id";
            drpCity.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Below is the code i which is used to bind the records in dropdowns

```
protected void grdLocationView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        FillCitiesByStateId();
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            drpCity = e.Row.FindControl("drpCities") as DropDownList;
            drpState = e.Row.FindControl("drpStates") as DropDownList;
            objCity.StateId = Convert.ToInt32(drpState.SelectedValue);
            drpCity.DataSource = objCity.GetCitiesByStateId();
            drpCity.DataTextField = "Name";
            drpCity.DataValueField = "Id";
            drpCity.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide any suggestion whats going wrong with it

Comment: Please include the exception details.

Comment: It theows "Object reference not set to an instant of an object."

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the line that always errors you can roll over objCity and drpState to see which object is a null reference. Have you identified this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are only calling the FillCitiesByStateId() for appropriate row types. Maybe you're calling it for a footer row?

[DataControlRowType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx)

instead of:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    FillCitiesByStateId();
}
```

try:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
{
    FillCitiesByStateId();
}
```